# Running spago build returns error installing dependencies

Tags: purescript, spago

I just started with purescript. Running spago build always return an error which says -

```
Failed to install dependency "effect"
Git output:
fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.
Aborting installation
[error] Installation failed
[error] Error:
[error] ExitFailure 1
```

Any clue as to where I'm going wrong?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4XKv.png

Comment: Have you tried running the same command again?

Comment: yeah dozens of times. same result

Comment: Try removing the `.spago` directory

Answer (score 1):

If you just installed purescript compiler or the spago package manager globally using:

```bash
npm install -g purescript
npm install -g spago
```

Then,
Please close your terminal / IDE / Editor **completely** and then reopen. Everything should work then.

PS: On VSCode, restarting via `Reload Windows` does not do the trick. Close and restart.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced and solved this problem in Windows 11.  The root cause of my problem was attempting to run spago inside a directory managed by Dropbox.

My solution was to move my build directory to somewhere not managed by Dropbox, but this is not ideal because I would like my work to be automatically backed up and shared between devices.

I'd be interested to hear if anyone has better solutions using spago (and git) and Dropbox together on Windows 11.  Ideally, there should be some way to make git less sensitive to whatever hidden files Dropbox is sticking in folders.